# Extended Euclidean algorithm and modular multiplicative inverse element

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x

After my first exercise here is another. Again, this is exactly that: Exercise, which means that the output doesn't necessarily need to be beautifully formatted, etc. I probably have some variable naming issues around and also more general issues.

```
# coding=utf-8

"""Basic usage:
$ python xggt.py 3343 77
(1, -12, 521)
65
"""

import argparse

###############################################################################


def main():
    """Prints out the results of xggt().
    xggt() takes two non-optional integers as arguments.
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('num_1', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('num_2', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if (args.num_1 == 0) and (args.num_2 == 0):
        print("Please enter two positive integers.")
    else:
        print(xggt(args.num_1, args.num_2))
        print(modinv(args.num_1, args.num_2))

###############################################################################


def xggt(num_1, num_2):
    """Implements the Extended Euclidean algorithm.
    Returns the greatest common divisor of two integers > 0.
    Also returns the coefficients of Bézout’s identity.
    """

    if num_1 % num_2 == 0:
        return(num_2, 0, 1)
    else:
        gcd, lin_fact_1, lin_fact_2 = xggt(num_2, num_1 % num_2)

        lin_fact_1 = lin_fact_1 - num_1 // num_2 * lin_fact_2

        return(gcd, lin_fact_2, lin_fact_1)

###############################################################################


def modinv(num_1, num_2):
    """Returns the modular multiplicative inverse of two integers > 0
    """

    gcd, lin_fact_1, _ = xggt(num_1, num_2)

    if gcd != 1:
        return None
    else:
        return lin_fact_1 % num_2

###############################################################################


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The egcd function (alias `xggt`) is nice and tight. I like it, but my head spins trying to match it against the math... Perhaps it would be easier to see the elegance of it if you used shorter names (single letters, corresponding to the letters u, v, s, r used in the formulas).

Comment: I'd lose the `else` in xggt, though. It is confusing because it's superfluous.

Comment: @DarthGizka Variable naming was my biggest concern, too. Also thank you for pointing out the unnecessary `else`.

Comment: @kleinfreund: There seem to be some (copy/paste?) errors  in your program, it does not run: 1) `parser` is undefined in `main()` 2) `lin_fact_2` is undefined in `xggt()`. The first error is easy to fix, but the second makes it difficult to understand your algorithm.

Comment: @kleinfreund: I assume it should be `gcd, lin_fact_1, lin_fact_2 = xggt(num_2, num_1 % num_2)` in `xggt()`.

Comment: @MartinR Ouch, thanks for pointing that out. The `_` was meant to go in `modinv()`, because `lin_fact_2` is not needed there. I swapped it around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the input validation:

> ```
> if (args.num_1 == 0) and (args.num_2 == 0):
>     print("Please enter two positive integers.")
> else:
>     print(xggt(args.num_1, args.num_2))
>     print(modinv(args.num_1, args.num_2))
> ```

The message *"Please enter two positive integers."* contradicts with the condition:
*if both numbers are 0*. I think you meant more like this:

```
if args.num_1 > 0 and args.num_2 > 0:
    print(xggt(args.num_1, args.num_2))
    print(modinv(args.num_1, args.num_2))
else:
    print("Please enter two positive integers.")
```

I also removed redundant parentheses.

You had redundant parentheses in other places too:

> ```
>     return(num_2, 0, 1)
>     # ...
>     return(gcd, lin_fact_2, lin_fact_1)
> ```

These are all unnecessary, so I recommend to remove them.

You can simplify `x = x - ...` with `x -= ...`, for example here:

```
# instead of this:
# lin_fact_1 = lin_fact_1 - num_1 // num_2 * lin_fact_2
lin_fact_1 -= num_1 // num_2 * lin_fact_2
```

Other than these minor issues, I think this is good and clean code! The names seem quite fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Some general feedback:

- Take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) and check your code with http://pep8online.com/
- Don't write those `#########` lines, because PEP8 says:

  > Separate top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
- If you add `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line, people can directly execute your code (on Linux machines at least). This is called [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). See [my article](http://martin-thoma.com/what-does-usrbinpython-mean/) for a very short explanation.
- `ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)` is very nice.
- Do you know [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)? I think they are very neat if you have simple functions that have parameters of integers and output of integers.

Comment: The code follows PEP8. I use it from the command line. What's wrong with the separation lines? Could you elaborate on what the `#!... python` does exactly for Linux users, please? Also, I looked at doctests and I use them now. Thank you.

Comment: @kleinfreund: I've extended my answer a little bit. What is wrong with separation lines? Well, it is not commonly used. We (the community of Python developers) have PEP8 to make code look similar, even if many different people write it. If it looks familiar, it is easier to read. In Python, top level functions should get separated by two blank lines. Not by `####` lines.